Make camera stop following HMD in collab viewer VR template Unreal Engine
How do I make camera stop following Head Mounted Device in collab viewer VR template Unreal Engine? So basically it should look like a static image in VR mode.
I am using Unreal Engine Version 5.2.1.

As in... stopping the motion tracking in the HMD?

No just make the in game camera stop following the hmd device. In the normal VR template I have an option “lock to hmd” which I can disable, but I can’t find something similar in Collab viewer template

@Fritz can you help me?

Actually I found the solution
There is an option lock to hmd on the camera

my bad
